# Do all Playstation consoles use 3.3V for controller port signalling?

Tags: controllers, ps2, ps1

I have read conflicting reports of what voltage Playstation 1 and 2 controller ports use. Some say 3.3V, some say 3.7V and some say 5V.

Does anyone know for certain that all official Sony hardware is 3.3V, or were some machines 5V?

Answer (score 1):

The official SONY Controllers will operate on 3.3V, and not on 5V, however the unofficial controllers mostly will work on 5V. All controlers WILL work on 3.3V.